# CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod XXXX in Podfile

Tags: ios, flutter

When I do `pod install` I get the following error:

[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "simple_permissions":
  In Podfile:
    simple_permissions (from `.symlinks/plugins/simple_permissions/ios`)

Specs satisfying the `simple_permissions (from`.symlinks/plugins/simple_permissions/ios`)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.

```
.....Podfile.....

# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
 platform :ios, '10.0'
# platform :ios

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def parse_KV_file(file, separator='=')
  file_abs_path = File.expand_path(file)
  if !File.exists? file_abs_path
    return [];
  end
  generated_key_values = {}
  skip_line_start_symbols = ["#", "/"]
  File.foreach(file_abs_path) do |line|
    next if skip_line_start_symbols.any? { |symbol| line =~ /^\s*#{symbol}/ }
    plugin = line.split(pattern=separator)
    if plugin.length == 2
      podname = plugin[0].strip()
      path = plugin[1].strip()
      podpath = File.expand_path("#{path}", file_abs_path)
      generated_key_values[podname] = podpath
    else
      puts "Invalid plugin specification: #{line}"
    end
  end
  generated_key_values
end

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Firebase/Firestore'


  # Flutter Pod

  copied_flutter_dir = File.join(__dir__, 'Flutter')
  copied_framework_path = File.join(copied_flutter_dir, 'Flutter.framework')
  copied_podspec_path = File.join(copied_flutter_dir, 'Flutter.podspec')
  unless File.exist?(copied_framework_path) && File.exist?(copied_podspec_path)
    # Copy Flutter.framework and Flutter.podspec to Flutter/ to have something to link against if the xcode backend script has not run yet.
    # That script will copy the correct debug/profile/release version of the framework based on the currently selected Xcode configuration.
    # CocoaPods will not embed the framework on pod install (before any build phases can generate) if the dylib does not exist.

    generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.join(copied_flutter_dir, 'Generated.xcconfig')
    unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
      raise "Generated.xcconfig must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
    end
    generated_xcode_build_settings = parse_KV_file(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    cached_framework_dir = generated_xcode_build_settings['FLUTTER_FRAMEWORK_DIR'];

    unless File.exist?(copied_framework_path)
      FileUtils.cp_r(File.join(cached_framework_dir, 'Flutter.framework'), copied_flutter_dir)
    end
    unless File.exist?(copied_podspec_path)
      FileUtils.cp(File.join(cached_framework_dir, 'Flutter.podspec'), copied_flutter_dir)
    end
  end

  # Keep pod path relative so it can be checked into Podfile.lock.
  pod 'Flutter', :path => 'Flutter'

  # Plugin Pods

  # Prepare symlinks folder. We use symlinks to avoid having Podfile.lock
  # referring to absolute paths on developers' machines.
  system('rm -rf .symlinks')
  system('mkdir -p .symlinks/plugins')
  plugin_pods = parse_KV_file('../.flutter-plugins')
  plugin_pods.each do |name, path|
    symlink = File.join('.symlinks', 'plugins', name)
    File.symlink(path, symlink)
    pod name, :path => File.join(symlink, 'ios')
  end
end

# Prevent Cocoapods from embedding a second Flutter framework and causing an error with the new Xcode build system.
install! 'cocoapods', :disable_input_output_paths => true

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'NO'
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Remove pod and try installing it again.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`simple_permissions` seems not working below 10.0. You need to update the ios platform version to minimum of 10.0 or later.

Please update the `Podfile` platform version also add `use_frameworks!` after the platform

```
platform :ios, '10.0'
use_frameworks!
```

Comment: "Module 'simple_permissions' not found"
when i update the version then, receive this error.

Comment: Would you please share the Podfile with your question?

Comment: Please check the question now.

Comment: Please add `use_frameworks!` after `platform :ios, '10.0'` line.

Comment: Yes, it is working completely on Simulator @Faysal Ahmed

Answer (score 3):

Please update your master repo before installing or updating the pods. You can update master repo with command in terminal.

> pod repo update

If you get same problem again then update your pod repo version .

> Latest Vesion :- sudo gem install cocoapods
>
> For pre released version :- sudo gem install cocoapods --pre

Hope this will be helpful for you.

Comment: Thank you bro. Correct answer.